# Zend Framework - Searching for text on a website

Tags: php, parsing, fopen, zend-framework

Me: New to Zend Framework

Objective : Search for the number of views for specific youtube videos

To keep things simple I though I should just take the youtube api for a video and search within the page for the word "viewcount" and take the data from there. 
Example: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZDG90nkL79c"

My question is how could I go about doing this in Zend Framework? I already did something like this in PHP with `fopen` and `preg_match`. I tried searching online for a solution but didn't find any good examples. What I think I should use is `Zend_HTTP_Client`, but I can't figure it out.

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a few lines of code on how to open the page and look for a word.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the Youtube API component in ZF? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html

Comment: I've looked at it but I can't figure out how to use it to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Zend_Gdata_Youtube:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_Youtube(null, // can pass instance of Zend_Http_Client
                             'Company-AppName-Version', // name of your app
                             $clientId, // issued by the YouTube dashboard
                             $developerKey // issued by the YouTube dashboard
                            );
$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('ZDG90nkL79c');
$viewCount  = $videoEntry->getVideoViewCount();
```

This way is probably easier but I'm not sure what else you want it to do.

### Using Zend_Http_Client and DomDocument

```
$hc = new Zend_Http_Client(
            'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ZDG90nkL79c')
$response = $hc->request();

if ($response->getStatus() == 200) {
    $domDoc = new DomDocument();
    $domDoc->loadXml($response->getBody());
    $stats = $domDoc
                ->getElementsByTagNameNS(
                    'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007',
                    'statistics'
                    )
                ->item(0); // Should be just one item in DomNodeList

    $viewCount = $stats->attributes->getNamedItem('viewCount')->nodeValue;
}
```

This second error will fail badly if there are errors in the XML or expected nodes are not present.